# How to store coordinates for comparison with later coordinates

Tags: c++, c++11

This is homework. 
I got a robot that travels a grid. I need to store every coordinates he visits and then check if he has visited them before. Right now i am storing the coordinates in a Pair but how can i store the Pair in a list/array so i can compare later coordinates he visits with it and add it to the list if he has not been there before?

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <list>



using namespace std;

void check (pair<int, int> foo)
{
    int points[10000];

    cout << "x " <<foo.first;
    cout << "y "<< foo.second << endl;
}

int main()
{

int numberOfLines = 0;
string strDirection;
int counter = 0;
cin >> numberOfLines;

do
{
    counter++;
    int tempStrSize = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int intDirection = 0;

    cin >> strDirection;
    tempStrSize = strDirection.size();
    char direction[tempStrSize];
    pair<int, int> foo;
    for(int i = 0; i<tempStrSize; i++)
    {
        direction[i] = strDirection.at(i); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tempStrSize; i++)
    {
        if(direction[i] == 'h' || direction[i] == 'H')
        {
            if(intDirection == 3)
            {
                intDirection = 0;
            }
            else if(intDirection != 3)
            {
                intDirection++;
            }
        }
        else if(direction[i] == 'v' || direction[i] == 'V')
        {
            if(intDirection == 0)
            {
                intDirection = 3;
            }
            else if(intDirection != 0)
            {
                intDirection--;
            }
        }
        else if(direction[i] == 'f' || direction[i] == 'F')
        {
            if(intDirection == 0)
            {
                y++;
                foo = make_pair(x,y);

            }
            if(intDirection == 1)
            {
                x++;
                foo = make_pair(x,y);

            }
            if(intDirection == 2)
            {
                y--;
                foo = make_pair(x,y);

            }
            if(intDirection == 3)
            {
                x--;
                foo = make_pair(x,y);

            }
        }
        check(foo);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;

}
while(counter < numberOfLines);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: if you only to store where the robot has been, not the order of those positions, then storing the visited pairs in a `std::set` will make the search both easy and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Map or an unordered_map:

```
#include <unordered_map>

unordered_map<pair<int, int>,bool> visitedPoints;

bool checkVisited(pair<int, int> &coords)
{
    return visitedPoints.find(coords) != visitedPoints.end();
}

void addVisited(pair<int, int> &coords)
{
    if(!checkVisited(coords)) visitedPoints[coords] = true;
}
```

Just to check if the pair is in the map and save the visited points.

Comment: There is no benefit in using a `map` over a `set` when the `map`'s value type is just `bool`.

Comment: @DanielFrey, Thanks for the point, thats true, its just for personal likes and that I think its useful for other operations he may need. :D

Comment: I ended up by storing the point in a vector, sorted the vector and ran a binary_search on it to find if the point had been visited. Was not able to figure this unordered_map thing out. Thanks for the answer though, it was appreciated.